# arrays of VHDL protected types

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to make better use of VHDL `protected` types, so I threw together the following test (just for illustration, of course - my actual use case is considerably more complex):

```
type prot_type1 is protected
  procedure set (new_data : integer);
  impure function get return integer;
end protected prot_type1;

type prot_type1 is protected body
  variable data : integer := 0;

  procedure set (new_data : integer) is
  begin
    data := new_data;
  end procedure set;

  impure function get return integer is
  begin
    return data;
  end function get;
end protected body prot_type1;
```

This compiles. However, the following line does not:

```
type prot_type1_array is array (natural range <>) of prot_type1;
```

Ashenden says (3rd Ed., p. 589) "Protected types cannot be used as elements of ... composite types". This is unfortunate. I was hoping to be able to create another protected type with the body:

```
type prot_type2 is protected body
  variable data : prot_type1_array(0 to 3);

  procedure set (idx : natural; new_data : integer) is
  begin
    data(idx).set(new_data);
  end procedure set;

  ...
end protected body prot_type2;
```

and avoid duplicating the code in `prot_type1.set()` (which is admittedly trivial in this case, but would be much more complex in my actual use case). It seems my only choice, though, is (1) to basically rewrite the entirety of `prot_type1` except with an array type for my private variable. Or (2), flatten the array internally, like:

```
type prot_type2 is protected body
  variable data0 : prot_type1;
  variable data1 : prot_type1;

  procedure set (idx : natural; new_data : integer) is
  begin
    case idx is
      when 0 =>
        data0.set(new_data);
      when 1 =>
        data1.set(new_data);
      when others =>
        -- handle exceptions here
    end case;
  end procedure set;

  ...
end protected body prot_type2;
```

This works, but is mildly undesirable for small arrays, and is *extremely* undesirable for large arrays. Is there another way?

Comment: Maybe use of `access` type with `integer` array in the `prot_type`could be a possibilities.  A `prot_type` that always operates on array could then be created, with an `init` method where the size of the array is specified.  The default size can then be 1, and default `idx` can be 0, so the use of `prot_type` would default to scalar operation, but still support array operation when required.  Would the fit your real work scenario ?

Comment: Good idea, and worth a try. My bigger concern is re-use of existing protected types, though. If I am provided a scalar protected type in some IP package, for example...

Comment: @Morten, that is exactly what I do in my scoreboard package.  As an open source IP provider, I find this very annoying to have to do.  Writing a tagged scoreboard that provides commands to drop certain items is challenging enough without adding the extra complication that internally I have to create an array of scoreboards.  In the VHDL Standards group, we have a proposal to fix this.  Make sure to download the priorities sheet and vote.  If you are interested in the scoreboard package, send me an email.

Comment: @Jim - Do you have any insight as to why this was not already allowed?

Comment: No requests for it during 2008 revision.

Answer (score 1):

here is a suggestion based on Morten Zilmer comment. The `prot1_type` get an access on integer instead of a unique integer. I have used function append, remove and get to manage the integer values.

Here is the code :

```
type array_int is array (natural range <>) of integer;
type a_integer is access array_int;

type prot_type1 is protected
  -- add a new value at the end of the vector
  procedure append (new_data : integer); 
  -- remove a value from the vector, return 0 ik OK, -1 is the item doesn't exist
  impure function remove (index : integer) return integer;
  -- return the integer value of the item
  impure function get(index : integer) return integer;
end protected prot_type1;

type prot_type1 is protected body

  variable data : a_integer;

  procedure append(new_data : integer) is
    variable temp : a_integer;
  begin
    -- create a temporary vector with the new values
    temp := new array_int'(data.all & new_data);
    -- free memory of the real vector
    Deallocate(data);        
    -- reallocate the real vector with the good values
    data := new array_int'(temp.all);
    -- free memory of the temporary vector
    Deallocate(temp);   
  end procedure append;

  impure function remove(index : integer) return integer is
    variable temp : a_integer;
  begin
    if (index > data'length-1 or index < 0) then  -- not sure if the vector is (0 to length -1) or (1 to length). to be tested !!!
      return -1;
    else
      -- create a temporary vector with the new values
      temp := new array_int'(data(0 to index-1) & data(index+1 to data'length-1));
      -- free memory of the real vector
      Deallocate(data);        
      -- reallocate the real vector with the good values
      data := new array_int'(temp.all);
      -- free memory of the temporary vector
      Deallocate(temp);
      return 0;
    end if;
  end function remove;

  impure function get(index : integer) return integer is
  begin
    return   data(index);
  end function get;

end protected body prot_type1;
```

Comment: Compilation is OK, some tests have to be made to be sure that pointers management is done well.

Comment: This is a decent solution, but I'd really like the type to behave more like an array, with completely random access, not a pseudo-linked list.